# SQL Server 2008 R2 database mirroring - is it possible to have a secondary server for multiple primary servers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring

Scenario is that I have two servers running SQL Server 2008 R2 (64-bit), let's call them **DB1** and **DB2**. I have set up database mirroring for all the databases on these servers so that **DB1** is the principal and **DB2** is the secondary.

Now the question is, can I set up database mirroring on a new server **DB3** running it as principal and have **DB2** work as a secondary for both **DB1** and **DB3**? Or will I need a separate new secondary server (**DB4**) for **DB3**? Would this configuration be possible using separate instances on **DB2**?

Answer (score 3):

A SQL Server instance can host multiple mirroring partnerships. Mirroring is between databases and databases are hosted on SQL Server instances, so choosing a name like 'DBx' for servers is a rather poor choice. Lets call the instances SRV1, SRV2 and SRV3 and the databases DB1 and DB2. What *is* possible is:

- to have the database DB1 mirrored by SRV1 (primary) and SRV2 (secondary)
- to have the database DB2 mirrored by SRV3 (primary) and SRV2 (secondary)

But the question is *What do you use mirroring for?* Primarily it is a High Availability feature. The question is: **will the SRV2 instance be able to take over the primary role for both DB1 and DB2 in case of failover**? Nothing prevents both SRV1 *and* SRV3 from suffering a problem at the same time. Also, if SRV2 suffers a disaster, you will have to come up with a backup plan to restore the HA for *both* DB1 and DB2. Are you prepared to handle all these cases?

> Would this configuration be possible using separate instances on DB2?

Yes, but is not necessary.

Comment: I tried it out and it works fine, thanks for your answer.
Of course SRV2 needs to be able to handle all databases it mirrors, I think the biggest problem would be that it would run out of working threads if the amount of databases mirrored is big (150+).